# Computing product measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, product-measure

I'm dealing with this case:

Let $(X,\mathcal{X},\mu), (Y,\mathcal{Y},\nu)$ measurable spaces, with $X=Y=[0,1],\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{Y}=$ Borel in $[0,1].$ Let $\mu$ the Lebesgue Measure and $\nu$ the counting measure.

Now, let $D=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y:x=y\}.$ I'm trying to calculate the measure of $D$ with the product measure $\pi.$

I know that $\pi(A\times B)=\mu(A)\times\nu(B),$  but I can't write $D$ as a product of two rectangles in $Z=X\times Y$. So, I'm trying to build some sequences $(A_{n})\in\mathcal{X},(B_{n})\in\mathcal{Y}$ such that $D=\lim(A_{n}\times B_{n})$, but I didn't get it.
What can I do?

EDIT: Remember that $(Y,\mathcal{Y},\nu)$ is not a $\sigma-$finite space, so I cannot use Fubini or Tonelli here. Not even the following Lemma:

[image]

Comment: Can you use Fubini (or rather Tonelli)?

Comment: @copper.hat no, beacuse $(Y,\mathcal{Y},\nu)$ is not $\sigma-$ finite, since $\nu$ is the counting measure.

Comment: Good point. ${}{}$

Comment: It can be defined as the outer measure of the rectangles, in which case the measure of $D$ must be $\infty$.

Comment: Any countable collection of sets $U\times V$ covering $D$ with $U \in \mathcal X, V \in \mathcal Y$ must contain at least one set where $V$ is uncountable.